# How to get an object with the maximum number of contacts on the foreign key in EF

Tags: c#, sql-server, entity-framework

I have two classes Employee and Click

```
public class Click
{
    public Guid Id { get; set; }
    public Guid EmployeeId { get; set; }
    public Employee Employee { get; set; }
}
public class Employee
{
    public Guid Id { get; set; }
    public ICollection<Click> Clicks { get; set; }
}
```

How can I get the employees with the highest number of clicks?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can order the employees by count of clicks:

```
var query= context.Employees.OrderByDescending(e=>e.Clicks.Count());
```

If you have disabled lazy loading you also will need to call `Include` extension method:

```
var query= context.Employees.Include(e=>e.Clicks).OrderByDescending(e=>e.Clicks.Count());
```

Now, if you want to select an specific amount of employees you can use `Take` extension method:

```
var query= context.Employees.OrderByDescending(e=>e.Clicks.Count()).Take(10);
```

### Update

To get the employee with the highest number of click:

```
var employee= context.Employees.OrderByDescending(e=>e.Clicks.Count()).FirstOrDefault();
```

Comment: How to get one employee with the highest number of clicks?

Comment: No. As in the answer above, but with `FirstOrDefault()` instead of `Take`